# Matlab - multithreading on single core

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parfor

I am working on simple computation program that consist of three functions.

First f1() generates some kind of data and stores it in a buffer (vector or queue or whatever).

Second f2() takes that data and do some computations on it and results stores in another buffer.

Third function f3() visualizes (creates plots, reports, etc) on results of f2().

That three functions needs to run at the same time on single core machine. I know about PARFOR loop and matlabpool. But it can create max number of threads (workers) = min(8, 'number of cores in machine'). Is there any solution to create a few threads in matlab on single core machine?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but with each function using taking the output of the previous function as input, it sounds like they all need to run sequentially rather than parallelly.

Comment: f1 and f2 stores its result in a kind of buffer so all functions can be run independently. If buffer is empty it does nothing, if not empty it computes that data. But all functions must run in parallel

Comment: Are the functions deterministic? Cause on first look I don't see why they would need to run 'all the time'.

Comment: This is a simulation of a simple real-time signal processing system. First function generates noise and some signals. This is not deterministic. Functions needs to run 'all the time' until user terminate whole program. I just need some hint how to create new threads in matlab on single core machine. I can't believe that such a powerful tool as MATLAB doesn't support such a basic thing.

Comment: just for clarification - so f2 and f3 are deterministic?

Comment: Yes, they are. Function f2 does the FFT on data generated in f1 and f3 displays that FFT in a known way.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have several options:

1. make your own threading. Basically it would be just one loop that continuously calls the functions.
2. Use an observer pattern to have the results update once the dependent input changes (is actually also a threading - but keeps the functions from recalculating already evaluated input)
3. start several matlab processes on your machine and have them send/receive the data through some protocol (ports or files).

Comment: Ok, this will probably work. But the problem is, that f1 generates signal vector (1024 complex numbers) every 10ms - this is hard requirement and there can't be any delays. Function f2 (FFT and other calculations) probably will need a little more time to finish. So data from f1 must be stored in a kind of buffer. If buffer for f1 is full, it starts to override data. So f2 must run in different, independent thread. In other way it could slow down signal generation what is forbidden.

Comment: Wow - that's some demanding requirements. I remember seeing something about scheduler and jobs that might provide some of the functions - but never could get it working on my machine.